# [Meta] Community Wiki- Site Question

Tags: meta

Can I get a better explanation as to what a community wiki is?
I can't seem to find a good definition on the site or FAQs.

(If we don't want this question mixed into the homebrewing vibe of questions please feel free to delete it.)

cheers

Comment: Can you precede the title with [meta] please?

Comment: What does teh [Meta] do?

Comment: Designates the question as site related, not beer related

Answer (score 3):

From my understanding, a Community Wiki question is a question that has no distinct "best answer". It's more subjective or informative. For example, `Methods of Fermentation Temperature Management` can have many answers, and many methods for each answer. This is more of an informational gathering topic than something like [How do I clean a sankey pump?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/285/how-do-i-clean-a-sankey-pump), which, while there are many possible answers, is a pretty straight forward question.

So I guess, in a more concise form:

Questions are reserved for direct Question - Answer formats.

Community Wikis are reserved for information gathering and sharing formats.

Does that make sense?

Comment: makes sense enough, I'll give it a try.